# How to react to a prop change without render it using mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am building a React + Mobx app and I have a situation where I have a component that does not render anything because it is all based on a 3rd party map API, but I need to react to some store property changes:

```js
componentDidMount() {
   mapApi.doSomething(this.props.store.value)
}

componentWillReact() {
   mapApi.doSomething(this.props.store.value)
}

render () {
   //workaround to make componentWillReact trigger
   console.log(this.props.store.value) 
   return null
}
```

Is there an elegant way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to react to something that not used in render function. You can do something like this:

```
@observer 
class ListView extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
   }

@observable filterType = 'all'

handleFilterTypeChange(filterType) {
  fetch('http://endpoint/according/to/filtertype')
    .then()
    .then()
}

  // I want the method that autoruns whenever the @observable filterType value changes
 hookThatDetectsWhenObservableValueChanges = reaction(
    () => this.filterType,
    filterType => {
      this.handleFilterTypeChange(filterType);
    }
 )
}
```

This solution is mentioned here https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/122#issuecomment-246358153

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  return false; // would never rerender.
}
```